# Remove first two elements from the database

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a HTML/PHP project. I have a list box called 'listnew' and
List items are loaded from the database. It's working perfectly.
But, now I want to remove first two elements from the list. 
I can remove the last element from the list. But that is not what I want.
I want to remove first two elements from the list.
Can anyone please help me to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use LIMIT keyword in sql query for selecting the row starting from the second row

Comment: can you post your html markup.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be skipping the first two items , this can be done by creating a counter variable that in this case the call " $ i " and initialize to 1.

When you're in the loop through the object of the database, make a comparison if the counter is less than 2 and continue without doing anything that you require for data conversion php.

```
$i = 1;
// initialize the variable for using over the while cycle
$listnew = "";

// assuming that you use mysqli

while($dataToPHP = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataFromMySQL)){
    if($i < 2){
        //Increase in one variable to get to 2 and so avoid the first two items on the list
        $i++;
        // The "continue" function skip the rest of the code in while cycle;
        continue;
    }
    // Rest of code yhat you need to get your list.
    $idItem = $dataToPHP['idListItem'];
    $name = $dataToPHP['listItemName'];
    $listnew .= "The id ".$idItem." has the name ".$name".<br />";
}
echo $listnew;
```

I think this is enough, but need more of your code to better understand how you make the call data from the database, and how you organize within the function (while) that extracts data.

Comment: This is how I load data from the database
<?php
include('config.php');
$var_value = $_GET['varname'];
$var_address1 = $_GET['varaddress1'];
$var_address2 = $_GET['varaddress2'];

$sql="SELECT address1, mapname, address1, placecoords  FROM places WHERE mapname = '".$var_value."'" ;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='input_name' multiple id='newlist'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<option value='". $row['placecoords'] ."'>" . $row['placecoords'] . "</option>";
  }
echo "</select>";
?>
I want to remove first two items after loading data from the database.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.  I sent my code with the previous comment. I have a function to remove last elemet from the list.                   function removeOptionLast()
{
  var elSel = document.getElementById('newlist');
  if (elSel.length > 0)
  {
    elSel.remove(elSel.length - 1);
  }
}   But, This is not what I want. I want to remove first two elements. Thanks.

Comment: `<?php
 include('config.php');
 $var_value = $_GET['varname'];
 $var_address1 = $_GET['varaddress1'];
 $var_address2 = $_GET['varaddress2'];
 $sql="SELECT address1, mapname, address1, placecoords FROM places WHERE mapname = '".$var_value."'" ;
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 echo "<select name='input_name' multiple id='newlist'>";
 $i = 0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $i++;
  $coords = $row['placecoords'];
  if ($i < 2){
   continue;
  }else if($i < (mysql_num_rows-1)){
   echo "<option value='".$coords."'>".$coords."</option>";
  }
 }
 echo "</select>"; ?>`

Comment: 1. the variables $var_addres? not used, if you think don't need, remove it. 2. initialize $i on zero because we need to count the two first elements AND remove the last element
 3. After while starts the $i variable increse by one ( $i++ )
 4. It's good practice and more "legible" convert the array data into a variable ($coords = $row['placecoords'])
 5. the "else if" is created to remove the last item on the list if you don't need to remove just delete the line. Keep the next and last curly bracket ( } ). I think this will help you!